# Opencv does not return correct fps for a webm file

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

When I try to find fps of a .webm file using following statement, it returns false fps.

```
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

It returns 1000 fps while actual fps is around 30. Can somebody tell what's the correct way of getting fps of a .webm file using opencv?

Comment: Can you upload the sample webm file? It works fine for me.

Comment: Here is the link to sample webm file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eusLwDF-wzq5tmQrnKxztJ5cZWnUxOxI

Comment: Way late, but any update on this?
Im facing the same issue